# split all array elements from json in java

Tags: java, arrays, json

How to split all array elements from JSON in Java

```
{
  "id": "405844",
  "username": "abc8",
  "password_hash": "dkjfhs7rjkds932dajk2900932",
  "role": "customer",
  "followed_stores" : 
   [
     {
       "id": "sda",
       "created": {
                "date": "2016-06-28 14: 43 : 28",
                "epoch": 1467125008563
       }
     }
  ],
  "followed_influencers": [
    {
      "id": "sda",
      "created": {
               "date": " 2016-06-28 14: 43 : 28",
               "epoch": 1467125008563
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want 3 JSON in 2 json I must have `followed_stores` array, `followed_influencer` array and in the last remaining json

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance of org.json.JSONArray with server response:

```
String serverResponse = "YOUR STRING";
JSONArray serverJsonArray = new JSONArray(serverResponse);
```

And then fill products list:

```
ArrayList<String> products = new ArrayList<>(serverJsonArray.length());
for(int i = 0; i < serverJsonArray.length(); i++){
     products.add(serverJsonArray.getString(i));
}
```

Or if you absolutely want a String array:

```
String[] products = new String[serverJsonArray.length()];
for(int i = 0; i < serverJsonArray.length(); i++){
     products[i] = serverJsonArray.getString(i);
}
```